# Django tastypie post request getting 401

Tags: python, rest

I am trying to do a POST request using tastypie in django.

My Resource looks like below:

```
class TestResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Test.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'test'
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json','xml'])
        always_return_data = True
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
```

And I am posting data like below:

```
import sys
import requests


DATA = {'field1':'posting data', 'field2':'123', 'field3':330303,}

def post(data):
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/'
    logging = {'verbose':sys.stderr}
    response = requests.post(url,data=data,config=logging)
    print "RESPONSE STATUS", response.status_code
    print "RESPONSE HEADERS", response.headers



if __name__=='__main__':
    post(DATA)
```

I am always getting 401, any idea?
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to set

```
Authorization=Authorization()
```

The default authorization implmented by tastypie is

```
ReadOnlyAuthorization()
```

which results in, you guessed it, readonly results, hence it will cause errors.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html

Do take note that it is not the best practice to do that however. There are other methods of Authorizations that can be used.